# Addon not appearing after installing

Tags: scripting, add-on, installation

I have an addon I'd like to install. I get a blue message at the bottom saying that the addon has been placed in the addons file location next to where Blender was downloaded... But when I go to enable the addon, it isn't there...

I've tried installing the zip file. I've tried unzipping the file and placing it in the addon location (and I get a red error message starting with the words "traceback most recent call last").
[image] I've tried removing all periods from the unzipped (and zipped) file... Nothing has worked... please help.

Comment: Recommend for paid addons ask any installation questions using feedback options at the place of purchase.

Comment: Only if they would respond...